# What's the benefit of using {standalone} instead of {article}?

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone, article

When I change `article` to `standalone` the result shows no difference except that the edge around the picture turning gray. Then what's the benefit of using `{standalone}` compared to `{article}`?

[image: standalone]

```
  \documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}    
  \usepackage{tikz}  
  \begin{document}  
  \begin{tikzpicture}  
  \draw[step=1cm, color=gray] (0, 0) grid (3, 2);       
  \end{tikzpicture}  
  \end{document}
```

[image: article]

```
  \documentclass[margin=10pt]{article}    
  \usepackage{tikz}  
  \begin{document}  
  \begin{tikzpicture}  
  \draw[step=1cm, color=gray] (0, 0) grid (3, 2);       
  \end{tikzpicture}  
  \end{document}
```

Comment: I mostly use standalone so that I don't have to crop images before copying them here.  BTW, the gray area is from [margin=10pt].

Comment: @JohnKormylo The white area around grid is from `[margin=10pt]`. They gray area is part of the display background which OP included when cropped the results.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The main advantages, in my opinion, are:

1. You can readily compile your figure and make modifications without compiling the whole document.
2. You can include the standalone .tex file using the `\includestandalone{filename}` command (from the [`standalone`](https://ctan.org/pkg/standalone) package). This command discards the preamble automatically so you don't need to cancel out the lines containing `\documentclass[]{}`, `\usepackage{}` etc. as you would do when using `\input{}` without the `standalone` package. Indeed, loading the `standalone` package will redefine the `\documentclass` macro so that also `\input` will ignore the preamble making the behavior of `\input` the same as `\includestandalone` command (without any option, see point 3 below).
3. The `\includestandalone[mode=image]{filename}` command is able to include the content of `filename.tex` as a pdf (it requires the option `-shell-escape` when you run pdflatex). This is particularly useful when the Ti*k*Z/pgfplots figure is complicated and expensive to create. It works like the `externalize` library while the option `mode=tex` is equivalent to include the code between `begin{tikzpicture}` and `\end{tikzpicture}` in your article (or whatever) document class. Furthermore, the option `mode=buildnew` let `standalone` to recognize whether the tex file is newer than its image and, in this case, the newer image is built and included as pdf for future compilations. This is (in my opinion) fantastic. To do that globally (for all of your standalone files) you can add the option `mode=buildnew` as a package option to `standalone`.
4. If you install ImageMagick, you can easily convert the `tikzpicture` to png/jpg and many other formats by simply running pdflatex (with the option `-shell-escape` activated) by simply adding `\documentclass[convert]{standalone}`.
5. The documentation of both the documentclass and package is well written and easy to understand. More advantages in using `standalone` over `article` are available there.

---

Disadvantages: if the images to be included in your document are few and computationally easy to create as well as the document itself can be quickly produced it may not be beneficial to create and include a standalone file.

Comment: You can use `\input` and the preamble will still be discarded - you don't need `\includestandalone` for this. (You need `standalone` to be loaded, of course.)

Comment: (1) and modified (2) are the real advantages, I think. The rest you can get easily anyway (e.g. with externalisation). I tend to combine externalisation with `standalone`, actually. And I always use `\input` rather than `\includestandalone` ;).

Comment: @cfr Thanks for your comments. In this answer I took the opportunity to show the potential of the command `\includestandalone`, not as a substitute to \input (i.e. `mode=tex`) but rather combined with the options `mode=image` and, most of all, `mode=buildnew` which I've found quite useful. I believe it may be tedious to find and delete (in order to update) an externalized pdf picture if there are hundreds of them, with standalone `mode=buildnew` I go faster... That being said, I will definitely include the behavior of `\input` for the sake of completeness. Thanks for pointing that out! :)

Comment: Yes, externalisation does that automatically i.e. it's the default, which is convenient.